# How to set SlugRelated field to a field within an object field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ... # fields omitted

class Prediction(models.Model):
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    ... # fields omitted

class Conversation(models.Model):
    sid = models.CharField()
    ... # fields omitted
```

Now I'm trying to create a model serializer for `Category` that would return me the following serialized object:

```
{
    "name":"blah",
    "conversations":[
        "2af22188c5c97256",    # This is the value of the sid field
        "073aef6aad0883f8",
        "5d3dc73fc8cf34be",
     ]
}
```

Here is what I have in my serializer:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conversations = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True,
             read_only=True, 
             source="prediction_set", 
             slug_field='conversation.sid')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Class
        fields = ('class_name', 'conversations')
```

However, this doesn't work because somehow django doesn't allow me to set slug_field to be a field that's within an object field. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try `conversation_sid`?

Answer (score 1):

You are modelling a Many-to-Many relationship between `Category`s and `Conversation`s with a explicit table called `Prediction`. The django way of doing this would be to explicitly state the Many-to-Many on either side of the relationship and specify `Prediction` as the "through-model":

Shamelessly stolen example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616476/serialize-a-foreingkey-and-many-to-many-fields-in-drf):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True,default=None)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True )

    ...

class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,blank=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
   categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, through='CatToPost')

   ...


class CatToPost(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    ...
```

This shows a good way to set up the relationship.

Equally shamelessly stolen from the answer by @Amir Masnouri:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = Category
            fields = ('name','slug')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      class Meta:
            model = Post  
            fields = ('id','{anything you want}','categories')
            depth = 2
```

This shows a nice way of achieving the nested serialization behavior that you would like.